# Listen changes on abstract variable

Tags: class, typescript, attributes, abstract

So I have this abstract class:

```
export abstract class Foo {
    // Can't do this, but I want to make sure the implementation sets "name"
    //abstract name: string;

    set name(value: string) {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

As I state in the code, I want to listen to the changes made to the attribute `name` inside Foo class, but keeping it abstract to make sure the programmer sets/implements the attribute somewhere.

Is there a way to make sure the programmer sets that variable or, at least, requires him to declare it.

Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a protected constructor which receives the `name`:

```
abstract class Foo {
    protected constructor(public name: string) {}
}
```

Or you can declare an abstract method which returns it:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public name: string;

    protected constructor() {
        this.name = this.getName();
    }

    protected abstract getName(): string;
}
```

You can call `getName` in a different place/time instead of in the constructor.